# How to put spark streaming data from kafka to JSONArray

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

kafka is Producing data where as Spark is consuming data.

```
JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(1000));
Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
Set<String> topics = Collections.singleton("mytopic");
JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,
                String.class, String.class, StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topics);
JSONArray json = new JSONArray();

directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
    rdd.foreach(record -> json.put(record._2));
});
System.out.println(json.length()); //printing length as zero
ssc.start();
ssc.awaitTermination();
```

I'm not able to put the values into JSONArray.

```
    Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json.JSONArray
```

Comment: Yes. I can see data

Comment: You cant access and change the json value inside foreach, map ? what do you want to do with each json value ?

Comment: I need to apply some filters on it and I need to send it to UI